# Populate DB2 parameter using Java for JDBC connection

Tags: java, database, db2

Recently I found that during DB2 connection, we could provide the end user id which could be used in case of charge back or to track consumption of CPU by a particular id.

I found on IBM site a parameter : ***qwhceuid***

Can someone tell me in which jar can we find this or how can I set this using Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_tjvstcli.html) might help, for the java program to use method setDB2ClientUser to supply the value.

Another suggestion may be for the java program to set the CLIENT_USERID special register via the URL bu appending `specialRegisters=CURRENT CLIENT_USERID=username;`